# Open source software that shows up Emergency Alert Message in full screen on a client desktop

Tags: windows, open-source

I have around twenty Win7 clients (digital signage - windows miniPCs + LCD 55” panel) inside one public place (airport). Each client shows 24/7 advertisements (videos, images,…) in a full screen mode.

All these windows clients are connected to a local airport network (LAN).

Airport wants to have an ability to show a full-screen ALERT message in case of emergency.

That is how I see this software to work:
Normal time: Our digital signage player plays its content

Emergency starts: An operator prepares a message, pushes SEND button and all these advertisement displays around airport show this message. The message is on top of digital signage player window.

Emergency gone: The operator pushes “HIDE” button, and this ALERT-overlay disappears.

Question: Are there any open-source software of such type?
We need an open-source, because it will be easier to obtain a security approval to use it inside airport LAN.

Thank you in advance.